# Library for generating document from MS Office templates

Tags: c#, reporting, microsoft-office

Can you suggest a library to generate dynamic documents (DOCX, PDF, XLSX) for C#? I would like to start from a Office document or template and merge an XML data model to get my final document.

Answer (score 0):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) can merge XML data into a DocX document and optionally create PDF.  From C# you would use the Cloud or Tornado options of Docmosis and make REST calls with your XML data.  Docmosis does not currently create XLSX type of documents. Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion provides file parsing libraries for [Excel - Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) , [Word - Essential DocIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio), [PDF - Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and other formats. You can use these libraries to generate dynamic documents.

Can be used with just .NET on a computer. No need to have Excel/Word/Acrobat installed.

[image: Essential XlsIO]

The whole suite of controls and libraries is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). Note: I work for Syncfusion.